# Use the definition of a Taylor series to find the first four nonzero terms of the series for f(x) centered at the given value of a.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Use the definition of a Taylor series to find the first four nonzero terms of the series for f(x) centered at the given value of a.

$f(x)=\sin(x)$, $a=\pi$

I know
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}*(x)^{2n+1}$$

Does centered at $\pi$ mean this?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\cdot (x-\pi)^{2n+1}$$

Comment: Hint: You need to obtain $\sin^{(n)}(\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $f(\pi)=0$, but the 1st term in your Taylor series is $1$.

By centering at $a$, it means its Taylor expansion takes the form $f(a)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$

Comment: Technically the first term of his expansion is $x-\pi$.  So you probably meant the coefficient of the $x^0$ term, which is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The Taylor series centered at $\pi$ is

$$\sin \pi+sin'(\pi)(x-\pi)+\frac{\sin''(\pi)}{2!}(x-\pi)^{2}+\dots$$ You are asked to find the first four non-zero terms. They are associated to \begin{cases}\sin'\pi=\cos\pi\\ \sin'''\pi=-\cos \pi \\ \sin^{(5)}\pi=\cos \pi\\ \sin^{(7)}\pi=-\cos \pi\end{cases} Can you write now the terms?

Comment: Thanks I got it. Is the f(x) that I posted up above only for Maclaurin Series? Can we not modify it or something?

Comment: If you have the Taylor series at $x=0$ $f(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$ then you can't expect that the Taylor series at $x=a$ has the same coefficients. That is, it will be $f(x)=\sum_n b_n (x-x_0)^n.$